# Can't get animation to work for some basic text

Tags: javascript, animation, jsfiddle

Hello all I'm trying to get this to work.

Source: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css

Here is my JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DpVrZ/4/

```
$('#animatedText').addclass('animated fadeInLeft');
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I suspect it might be the webkit issue. Perhaps I should use Moz instead.

Any input would be great thanks!

Comment: link jquery to the code and try it out

Comment: tried it. Don't work. I'm confused about something here syntax wise. ('animated fadeInLeft')is expressed in CSS as .animated.fadeInLeft. Does that need to be placed in the brackets the same way?

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved bro, checkout the fiddle here. Remember to include jQuery in your html code when you do the addClass :

I also changed some of the webkits to normal styles, eg.:

```
animation-fill-mode: both;
```

to

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DpVrZ/7/

Answer (score 0):

addClass is jQuery. I loaded jQuery in the fiddle, but it was not working again. And, webkit is a vendor prefix, which makes some CSS3 effects not officialy supported by Chrome, work.

Comment: Okay. So what do you suggest to fix the problem?

Comment: According to the Jquery API ...I assigned an #element already. So the add.class should be adding the .animation element from the css. Do I need to place that in?